# Swap each even pair of characters with next pair of characters in array

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I want to create an function which splits strings into two sets of characters, character by character, then merges the second set before the first, character by character. For example  string "*KILOS*" (**odd # of chars**) would split into "*KL*" "*IO*" then "*S*" where the final output would look like "*IKOLS*".Meaning for every odd case, the last character from original string holds the last place in the new string. The encode function expects s2 to point to a string containing a string that is converted from s1. Any help, hint would be appreciated! Thank you.

```
***//I HAVE DELETED MY CODE BECAUSE I ACTUAL STUDENTS MIGHT COPY IT, AND GET CAUGHT PLAGIARISING> SORRY>***
```

Comment: I guess I am not understanding the question.

Comment: Hey so sorry, but this is how my teacher posted his question. He gave us this output Enter a word: merging
Output: emgrnig

Comment: So it is swapping consecutive characters?

Comment: Exactly. User puts a word and then we are just merging two sets.

Comment: @coderredoc - I believe he is saying "take an even number of character **pairs** from a string (split them into odd/even) and if there is a final odd char -- leave it tacked on at the end of the encoded string. Otherwise, just put the encoded string together as odd/even/odd/even. (swapping each character in each set of pairs around)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: So `coderredoc` would be `ocedrrdeco`?

Comment: Yep, you got it.. Have fun `:)`

Comment: Sorry for poor english, I am from Italy. Came to USA for study. @David is right. For example if user types a word "APPLE" the output would be "PALPE"

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Thanks you are right.

Comment: @Ulta.: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Thank you. I just can't write the encode function. I have read the chapter in the book. But I don't know you to split then merge the sets. My teacher didn't go depth, so I was also lost in the class. Even a  hint would be ok.

Comment: @Ulta.: You mean this `APPLE ->PALPE` you can't write?

Comment: Yes sir. I can't write it, using this  `void encode(char *s1, char *s2) ` required function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is here the code you have written is complicated and simple looping over the string can solve the problem.

```
void convert (char *s1, char *s2){
  size_t len = strlen(s1);
  for( size_t i = 0; i < len; i+=2 ){
    if(i+1 < len){
      s2[i+1] = s1[i];
        s2[i] = s1[i+1];
    }else{
      s2[i] = s1[i];
    }
  }
  s2[len]=0;
}
```

If you have to use the function like this:-

```
char s[6]="hello";
char t[6];
convert(s,t);
printf("%s\n",t);
```

Here ofcourse it is considered that `s2` has enough memory to hold the processed string. This has literally nothing more than the copying logic. You are considering two characters each and then swapping them while copying. At last you reach a position when you are accessing an element which has no pair (odd number of elements). Then you simply copy it and move on.

In case you don't know what array subscripting means - let me tell you, `s1[i]` is same as `*(s1+i)`.

#### Edit1

Also in your adaptation of my code in the last line you have put `*s2 = 0`.
It should be

```
*(s2+len)=0;
```

Another thing is in your readline code you don't need these two lines. You can do it simply like this:-

```
int read_line(char *str, int n)
{
    int words; int store=0;
    while((words=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        if(store<n)
        {
            *str++=words;
            store++;
        }
    }
    *str=0;
    return store;
}
```

And

```
void encode(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int len = strlen(s1);
    for( int i = 0; i < len; i+=2 ){
        if(i+1 < len){
            *(s2+i+1) = *(s1+i);
            *(s2+i) = *(s1+i+1);
        }else{
            *(s2+i) = *(s1+i);
        }
    }
    *(s2+len)='\0'; //<---- note this
}
```

Comment: Hello @coderredoc Thank you so much. The program doesn't show the output, when implementing. I have updated my current code in the question. Also, teacher said not to use subscripting, he wants everything in pointer arithmetic. And one last thing, we haven't learn the size_t yet, so I will use something else.

Comment: @Ulta.: You yourself used array subscripting? Dont wait for teacher to teach you - `strlen` returns length in `size_t` and this code is fully functional.

Comment: Yes I have used the sub scripting, but he said not to use subscribing in the function. Yes sir, I have seen the size_t introduced with size_of. Moreover, I am not judging your response, i am saying the way my program behaving...My program says, Enter a word then I hit enter, and no output.

Comment: @Ulta.: Sorry you can change it to like this `s[i]` to `*(s+i)`. And also I have written the code for the function - you have to integrate with your existing code.

Comment: `void encode(char *s1, char *s2)
{
  size_t len = strlen(s1);
  for( size_t i = 0; i < len; i+=2 ){
    if(i+1 < len){
      *(s2+i+1) = *(s1+i);
        *(s2+i) = *(s1+i+1);
    }else{
      *(s2+i) = *(s1+i);
    }
  }
   *s2='\0';
}`

Comment: @Ulta.: yep..that's what I meant. Your other function works? (which takes inputs?)

Comment: Yes sir. I tested that program before I worked in the encode. When I do printf after calling read_line, it prints takes the input then prints the length of the string. So i think it is working efficiently. I have updated my code in the question above.

Comment: @Ulta.: Also think carefully what you are doing in other function. As an hint - make sure when you are incrementing the pointer that it doesn't point to outside of the char array. All the best. you can do it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you have showed me a direction. I will finish this :)

Comment: @Ulta.: Check the edit. Your `*s2 = 0` should be `*(s2+len)=0`.

Comment: Oh wow. Yes, I figured that *(s2+len)='\0' but didnot see *str = 0; Sorry i was busy working on my own, but saw your notification. May the coding gods bless your mind:)